# Conda Conflicts Not Resolving After Installing Packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am attempting to install a package called [Symtopo](http://materiae.iphy.ac.cn/symtopo) which is a Conda package from owner [materiae](https://anaconda.org/materiae). The package has dependencies and when I run `conda install` on it, it results in this error (my current Conda environment is running Python 3.7.4):

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a']
Package phonopy conflicts for:
symtopo -> phonopy=2.1.3
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> sqlite[version='>=3.29.0,<4.0a0']
Package libcxx conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']
Package h5py conflicts for:
symtopo -> h5py=2.9.0
Package pymatgen conflicts for:
symtopo -> pymatgen=2019.4.11
Package libffi conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
Package readline conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> pip
Package tk conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package abipy conflicts for:
symtopo -> abipy=0.6.0
Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.7.4 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
```

I was working on a completely clean Conda environment initially. After I created I ran `conda list` and had no packages installed. After getting these errors, I took some of the packages and put them into a requirements file and ran the install on them. My `conda list` now results in:

```
ca-certificates           2019.9.11            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1    conda-forge
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0
libffi                    3.2.1             h6de7cb9_1006    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1
openssl                   1.1.1c               h01d97ff_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h359304d_1
readline                  7.0               hcfe32e1_1001    conda-forge
setuptools                41.6.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               ha441bb4_0
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0
xz                        5.2.4             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h0b31af3_1006    conda-forge
```

I then attempted the install of the package again and got the same error I had before. I'm not understanding how this is possible because you can see that I now have, for example, `zlib`, `tk`, `xz`, installed. I'm not sure how to correctly resolve these conflicts because after installing the appropriate packages/versions, it does not seem to help.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suspected Cause

Judging from your build IDs, you're working with an **osx-64** platform. The dependency requirements for SymTopo look weird for all the **osx-64** builds, specifically, they require `pymatgen=2019.4.11.*`, which from searching Anaconda Cloud just doesn't exist. In the **linux-64** builds, however, this requirement is `pymatgen>=2019.4.11`, so I'm thinking the author has done this incorrectly, hence why you can't resolve a coherent package configuration.

---

## Possible Workarounds

Other than contacting the author and asking them to post some working builds, I think you have two possible courses of action:

1. Force Install
2. Using PyPI Builds

Either way, assume the resulting env will be fragile, so try to avoid any further unnecessary installations into it.

#### Force Install

If we assume that the `pymatgen=2019.4.11.*` really should be `pymatgen>=2019.4.11`
then you could just install all the prereqs (see YAML in next section), then use

```
conda install -n my_env --no-deps materiae::symtopo
```

It might be worth a try, but the Conda help (`conda install -h`) warns in no uncertain terms that doing this carries no guarantees.

#### Using PyPI Builds

Another way around this could be to [enable Pip interoperability in Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html), though this is a relatively experimental feature. The strategy would be:

1. Create an env, installing all the prerequisites as a mix of Conda and PyPI packages.
2. Enable the Pip interoperability *just for this env*.
3. Install SymTopo from Conda.

I tested this and got it to work with the following YAML as the initial env definition:

**symtopo-prereqs.yaml**

```
name: symtopo_env
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3.7
 - h5py=2.9.0
 - phonopy=2.1.3
 - pip
 - pip:
   - abipy==0.6.0
   - pymatgen==2019.4.11
```

The commands are then:

```
conda env create -f symtopo-prereqs.yaml
conda activate symtopo_env
conda config --env --set pip_interop_enabled true
conda install materiae::symtopo
```

Again, I would regard this env as quite fragile ([for the reasons given here](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)) and avoid any more installs to it.

Note that I found using `abipy` from the recommended channel led to conflicts, so I opted to just use the PyPI version. Unfortunately, this leads to lots of packages coming from PyPI, but it does get everything installed.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much. I had come to the conclusion that the original author has done a few things incorrectly and due to there being no public GitHub, there was nowhere to post this. It seems like the PyPI is the most reliable way to do thus far but will also send this over to the authors as well to hopefully clean up on a future update. Thanks so much for your help, trying this out now!

Comment: The installation worked great (it remains to be seen how stable the application actually is but this will get me up and running). Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @MillerMedia glad to help! Another thought I had was that perhaps those older versions of `pymatgen` got pulled from Anaconda Cloud, so it may not be entirely the author's fault.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm actually going to reach out to them to see if I can help them maintain this on the technical side so this is a very helpful place to start (I'll direct them to your answer as well for context). Thanks!